# can't get an output from scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

when I put

```
scrapy runspider divar.py -o data.json
```

in the terminal, I get an empty file. am I doing something wrong here? I want to get result of categories and subcategories from the URL I put in the start_urls and then put in the result and the print it and also get an json file. mostly json file.

```
import scrapy 

class ws(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wsDivar'
    result = []

    start_urls =["https://divar.ir/s/tehran"]
    def parse(self, response):
        for category in response.xpath("//*/ul[@class='kt-accordion-item__header']"):
            x = {'cats' : category.xpath("//*/ul[@class='kt-accordion-item__header']/a").extract_first()}
            result.append(x)
            yield(x)
            print(result)
            

           

        next_L =response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_L is not None:
            next_link = response.urljoin(next_L)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_link, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scrapy 

class ws(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wsDivar'
    start_urls =["https://divar.ir/s/tehran"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for category in response.xpath("//*/ul[@class='kt-accordion-item__header']"):
            x = {'cats' : category.xpath("//*/ul[@class='kt-accordion-item__header']/a").extract_first()}
            yield(x)

        next_L =response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_L is not None:
            next_link = response.urljoin(next_L)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_link, callback=self.parse)
```

if your XPath works fine. `yield` also print you the result.

instead of this:

`scrapy runspider divar.py -o data.json`

use this:

`scrapy crawl wsDivar -o data.json`

Also, run the command in project directory which supposed to include `scrapy.cfg` file.